# How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu using VMware tools?

Tags: vmware-tools

Experts. I've successfully installed VMware tools for Ubuntu. Everything seems to work fine, but shared folders were not mounted automatically.
How do I get them to work?

If I run `vmware-hgfsclient` in terminal, I get the list of shared folders, but `ls -l /mnt/hgfs` is empty. Actually there's no `hgfs` dir in `/mnt`. I know I should probably use the `vmware-hgfsclient` tool, but I realy don't know how.

P.S. I wouldn't ask if I could understand the `vmware-hgfsclient` help I've read.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The steps in this article http://www.wingfoss.com/content/how-to-install-vmware-tools-on-debian-ubuntu-centos followed by `vmware-config-tools.pl` worked for me.

Comment: with open-vm-tools installed, you should use vmhgfs-fuse for that, see #1 answer in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/580319/enabling-shared-folders-with-open-vm-tools

Comment: I have created a new Q&A for newer Ubuntu-s. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350352/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-version-18-04-using-vmware-tools

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I have set up on Windows 7 host with  Ubuntu 11.04 Desktop with VMware Tools installed on.

### Virtual Machine settings

- Folder sharing = Always Enabled
- Make sure you have at least one Folder shared between the host and guest

### On the Ubuntu Guest

- check /mnt/hgfs that you can access your shared folder.

  If you don't see your shared folders (automounted) inside `/mnt/hgfs` , run VMware configuration tools:

  `sudo vmware-config-tools.pl`
- update your fstab using the details below:

  `gksu gedit /etc/fstab`

  (I am using ubuntu desktop so use other text editor to enter the next line at the end of the file)

  `.host:/{shared-folder} /{path-to-mount-on} vmhgfs defaults,ttl=5,uid=1000,gid=1000   0 0`
- Restart your vm (You may need to restart few times or get error message saying unable to mount just skip the error and restart)

Comment: with {shared-fodler} you mean the NAME or something else ? For instance, if I'll run `vmware-hgfsclient` 
i'll get `hst_dwnloads` and `hst_ebooks`. So I should use on of them?

so for hst_ebooks it should look like:
`.host:/hst_dwnloads<white-space>/mnt/hgfs/ vmhgfs defaults,ttl=5,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`

or not ?

Comment: @V-Light if you `cd /mnt/hgfs/` then `ls -a` you'll see that share folders are auto mounted there.

When you do `sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/hst_ebooks ~/hst_ebooks` this will mount `hst_ebooks` into your home directory.

What you might be wanting to do is making is easy for you to use shared folders for that try above.

Comment: that's the problem. There's NOTHING in `/mnt/hgfs/` The dir ist empty.

Comment: @V-Light take a look at [How to Share folders with your Ubuntu Virtual Machine (guest)](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-share-folders-with-your-ubuntu-virtual-machine-guest/)

Comment: @Aizur, the guide didn't help. But after 'cleaning' (uninstalling open- and 'normal'-vmwaretools) I was finally able to install open-vm-tools and mount shared folders. Thank you for you advice with fstab

Comment: Re-running `sudo vmware-config-tools.pl` was enough for me.

Comment: +1 - I had to install the `vmware tools` by clicking on the VM menu on vmware workstation.

Comment: @V-Light how did you "clean"? I'm having similar problems that re-running the config aren't solving.

Comment: It seems the vmhgfs module does not compile against the 3.13 kernels (e.g. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). So make sure to check for errors in the vmware-config-tools.pl output. Source:  https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches/issues/4

Comment: My share folder is in /mnt/hgfs/   , and my host folder is C:/xampp/htdocs/thesharefolder.    So how do I type thìs : `.host:/{shared-folder}`

Comment: I want to mound the folder in "~" directory instead of "/mnt/hgfs".   In the meantime, is use a symbolic link : `ln -s /mnt/hgfs/thesharefolder ~/`

Comment: adding this line broke my installation, and I spend half hour to revert the issue.

Comment: E: Package 'gksu' has no installation candidate. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 218):

Most other answers are outdated. For Ubuntu 18.04 (or recent Debian distros), try:

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs/ -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```

If the `hgfs` directory doesn't exist, try:

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/ -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```

You may have use a specific folder instead of `.host:/`. In that case you can find out the share's name with `vmware-hgfsclient`. For example:

```
$ vmware-hgfsclient
my-shared-folder
$ sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/my-shared-folder /mnt/hgfs/ -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```

If you want them mounted on startup, update `/etc/fstab` with the following:

```
# Use shared folders between VMWare guest and host
.host:/    /mnt/hgfs/    fuse.vmhgfs-fuse    defaults,allow_other,uid=1000     0    0
```

I choose to mount them on demand and have them ignored by `sudo mount -a` and the such with the `noauto` option, because I noticed the shares have an impact on VM performance.

### Requirements

Software requirements may require installing the following tools beforehand:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Others have claimed the following are required:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant \
  linux-headers-virtual linux-image-virtual && dpkg-reconfigure open-vm-tools
```

### Official Article

How to configure VMware Tools Shared Folders Linux mounts ([60262](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/60262))

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; the other answers are completely out of date.

Comment: `fuse.vmhgfs-fuse` is the only filesystem that works for ubuntu 18.

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 19.10.  Dont forget to do "sudo mkdir /mnt/hgfs/" first

Comment: Can confirm, on Ubuntu 19.10 virtual machine running on Windows 10 Pro host, this worked. Specifically, `sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/ -o allow_other -o uid=1000`

Comment: @V-Light: please change the accepted answer to this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me perfectly on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I was able to get this working by creating a new share folder in both spots: `sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/share-folder /mnt/share-folder -o allow_other -o uid=1000`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked perfectly for me on ubuntu-22.04.2 for VMware Workstation

Answer (score 37):

run vmware-config-tools.pl, AGAIN!

Refer: [http://www.laotudou.com/vmware-player-share-folder.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20111026010902/http://www.laotudou.com/vmware-player-share-folder.html)

Comment: `vmware-config-tools.pl` is not available if using `open-vm-tools` from [Ubuntu-Software-Center](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/open-vm-tools) or compiled from source from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-vm-tools). In that case user must use `vmware-hgfsmounter` as [@snth](http://askubuntu.com/users/12598/snth) describes in his [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/30920/36961). It may be possible to use `open-vm-toolbox`, [tools and components for VMware guest systems (GUI tools) package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/open-vm-toolbox) from the Ubuntu software repository

Comment: this fixed it for me, if anyone doesn't know it's located under the VMWare tools after you untar.gz it in: `vmware-tools-distrib/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl'

Answer (score 19):

[UPDATE 2017-05-18] ***This answer is outdated for Ubuntu newer than 15.10 (Wiley)**. The executable [`vmware-hgfsmounter` has not been available in Ubuntu since 16.04LTS (xenial).](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=vmware-hgfsmounter&op=&cx=003883529982892832976%3A5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com%2F&ref=&ss=1872j594816j10) Although, `hgfsmounter` may still be available on other Linux distributions, since the [`hgfsmounter` function is still currently available in the upstream source code on GitHub](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/blob/master/open-vm-tools/hgfsmounter/hgfsmounter.c#L1008-L1022). If anyone has updated information, please comment or edit this answer, instead of down-voting, as I believe this answer may still be valid for older Ubuntu releases.*

*This answer also assumes that you are **not** using VMWare Tools from VMWare **but instead using `open-vm-tools` from your Linux distribution**. [VMWare decided to support this switch in 2015.](https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2015/09/open-vm-tools-ovt-the-future-of-vmware-tools-for-linux.html) [See KB2073803.](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2073803) Therefore this answer also assumes that your version of Ubuntu can install the open-vm-tools from it's software repository.*

## OUTDATED FOR UBUNTU > 15.10 (Wiley)

This worked for me using [open-vm-tools from Ubuntu Software Center (trusty-14.04LTS shown - please see update above)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/open-vm-tools):

```
cd /mnt
sudo mkdir hgfs
sudo vmware-hgfsmounter .host:/`vmware-hgfsclient` /mnt/hgfs
```

assuming of course that I had already enabled a shared folder from the host machine in VMware Player settings.

Note that [`vmware-hgfsclient`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man1/vmware-hgfsclient.1.html) returns the list of shared folders that are enabled in the VMware Player settings. This function is available for both open-vm-tools and vmware-tools.

Also note that [`vmware-hgfsmounter`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man8/vmware-hgfsmounter.8.html) is equivalent to

```
mount -t vmhgfs .host:/win7share /mnt/hgfs
```

or to adding to your `/etc/fstab` file

```
.host:/win7share /mnt/hgfs vmhgfs defaults 0 0
```

But the `vmware-hgfsmounter` function is not available using the [official vmware-tools from VMware](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware-tools-installation-configuration.pdf) that ships with the current [VMware player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/). Therefore, as the [currently accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/41386/36961) suggests, running the `vmware-config-tools.pl -d` fixes the problem.

Comment: Gave an error "share name is invalid". This syntax worked, however: `vmware-hgfsmounter .host:/<Share-Name> /mnt/hgfs` 
<Share-Name> is simply the name of the share as configured in VMWare

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderRechsteiner. Your syntax is probably better as it is more general. FYI, backticks around commands expand the command so since `vmware-hgfsclient` returns the "share name", then `\`vmware-hgfsclient\``, uses the returned "share name" as the argument for `vmware-hgfsmounter`. if you're getting "share name is invalid" try running `vmware-hgfsclient` and seeing what "share name" it returns. It may be a list, and that might be the problem.

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner Thanks for spotting that I had missed the file system seperator `/` in the host share!

Comment: Error: cannot canonicalize mount point: No such file or directory

Comment: @IgorG. Create the folder first with `mkdir /mnt/hgfs`, then it works.

Comment: `vmware-hgfsmounter` does not exist with the most recent Ubuntu open-vm-tools package (Ubuntu 16.04, open-vm-tools 10.0.7).

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem. The folder /mnt/hgfs/ appeared back again when I assured that open-vm was uninstalled. As follows

```
sudo apt-get purge open-vm-tools
sudo apt-get purge open-vm-tools-dkms
```

and reinstalled vmware-tools

Comment: Great point, I needed this after having uninstalled the vmware-tools manually and dkms was the one still providing some kernel modules.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling is a "windows newbie recipe", not a good practice.

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact problem. It turned out IT had installed some old version of VMWare tools with non-functioning vmhgfs kernel module.

My solution was to run the configuration with the clobber-kernel-modules setting to overwrite the existing vmhgfs module.

```
 sudo vmware-config-tools.pl -d --clobber-kernel-modules=vmhgfs
```

The `-d` selects all the defaults for you (remove it if you don't want the defaults).

Comment: After an Ubuntu upgrade that broke my sharing, an hour of trying lots of various things failed...but it was the clobber-kernel-modules=vmhgfs that finally made it work again.

Answer (score 6):

open-vm-tools would **NOT** build kernel modules until I first installed `linux-headers-virtual` (paired with `linux-image-virtual` of course). as soon as I installed the headers package, `dpkg-reconfigure open-vm-tools` resulted in successfully building and loading the kernel modules, specifically the `vmhgfs` module.

Comment: I purged my installed open-vm-tools, installed the linux headers and image packages you mentioned, then reinstalled the vmtools. I still do not have a loaded vmhgfs module nor can I load one (it doesn't exist). I cannot get the shared files to work with the open-vm-tools packages. I'm going to try the manual install of vmware tools mentioned in other answers.

Comment: This worked great with Ubuntu 16.4.1. No vmware tools needed, just those three packages and dpkg-reconfigure followed by shared folders disable / enable cycle from vmware settings.

Comment: packages `linux-headers-virtual` and `linux-image-virtual` do not exist anymore.

Answer (score 6):

### vmware-tools-patches worked for me; give this a  shot if nothing else works

> I've tested this on a fresh install (easy install) of ubuntu 16.10 on vmware workstation 12 pro

1. Go to https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches
2. Follow the `Quickest Start` instructions given there. Reproduced here:

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git
   $ cd vmware-tools-patches
   $ ./patched-open-vm-tools.sh
   ```

Comment: `vmware-tools-patches` worked for me also on Ubuntu 17.10 development release. But I followed the instructions found on the vmware forums: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/509898

Answer (score 5):

I've been having the same problem but I think I have just been able to make some progress.

Type `vmware-hfgs` and then press the `<Tab>` key which will show you that there is also a `vmware-hgfsmounter` command. If you call that without any options it will print some help that shows you how to call this as part of the `mount' command. Using that info I then ran the following which worked for me:

```
cd /mnt
sudo mkdir win7share
sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/win7share /mnt/win7share
```

I was then able to access the Win 7 share and copy files to and from there.

If you want to make this permanent then I suspect that you will need to edit the `/etc/fstab` file but I can't help you there yet.

Comment: If i execute 
`sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/hst_ebooks /mnt/hgfs/hst_ebooks`
i get an Error:
`Error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device`

Comment: Have you created the `/mnt/hgfs/hst_ebooks` mount point? I think in my case `/mnt/hgfs` already existed and in case there were any special event handlers watching that directory I rather created a directory under `/mnt` directly. Therefore try `sudo mkdir /mnt/hst_ebooks` and then try running the command again.

Comment: `sudo vmware-hgfsmounter <host:sharename> <dir>` runs the same commands as `sudo mount -t vmhgfs <host:sharename> <dir>` where <sharename> is `vmware-hgfsclient`

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the VMWare tools first, after that the `vmware-config-tools` can be used globally. For a more detailed guide, you can see [here](http://www.webtrunghieu.info/site/computer/sharing-files-and-folders-with-linux-guest-os-in-vmware-player).

Comment: Link seems broken.

Answer (score 3):

(applies to Mac VMware Fusion and Ubuntu file sharing)
When you are asked in vmware-config-tools.pl about whether you want HGFS, say yes! (The default is 'no' and you may have skipped over it when hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>). This should give you `/mnt/hgfs` after the tools are installed.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't still mount shared folders after installing `vmware-tools`, here is the resolution.

Previously, I couldn't mount windows shared folder after installing vmware tools. I didn't see any folders under /mnt/hgfs.

Finally, I got resolved this share folder mounting issue by installing `open-vm-dkms`.

Here are steps:

1. Ensure configured shared folder in VMWare Player
2. Install open-vm0dkms:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install open-vm-dkms
   ```
3. Hit the "Enter" all the way to allow default value
4. Mount Windows shared folder to Ubuntu VM:

   ```
   sudo mount  -t  vmhgfs  .host:/     /mnt/hgfs
   ```
5. check if mounting is successful

   ```
   df -kh
   ```

   You should see:

   ```
   .host:/         57657252 50247088   7410164  88% /mnt/hgfs
   ```

   Also check again if any folders under /mnt/hgfs. You should see folders under which.
6. Auto mount shared folder on startup

   There is a startup script called “open-vm-tools” with in /etc/init.d/ folder. Just add the below line in the start function.

   ```
   sudo mount  -t  vmhgfs  .host:/     /mnt/hgfs
   ```

Hope it can help.

Comment: This works for me with Windows 10 host and Xubuntu 14.04.2 client, thank you!

Comment: I get:

$ sudo apt-get install open-vm-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package open-vm-dkms

Comment: The following installs though: $ sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-dkms

Answer (score 1):

VMWare: 15.5.0 build-14665864
Windows 10 host, guest OS in the virtual machine; Ubuntu 20.04

```
$ tail -n 1 /etc/fstab 
vmhgfs-fuse     <-fill-in-echo-$HOME-here>/shares fuse    defaults,max_write=32768,allow_other         0    0
$ mkdir -p $HOME/shares && sudo mount shares
```

Make sure that the fstab line has `max_write` defined as above
*( I had trouble with higher values,

  you might even be safer with 32767 as that is the highest possible value in 15 bits )*.

The name of the folder you have defined as "share" in VMWare settings (for the current VM) will appear as a sub-folder in ~/shares/ .

*(Windows 10 host, used here - when this was found to be necessary)*

Comment: Ubuntu VMWare Player running an Ubuntu VM both (20.04) this is the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this problem is to edit 'inode.c' and change the line '888' to remove 'compat_truncate' function call (that is responsible for this problem on kernels 3.8.x). This file is inside 'vmware-tools-distrib', so you need to perform the following steps:

Extract VMWare-Tools (probably you will get a folder called vmware-tools-distrib).
Then:

```
 cd /vmware-tools-distrib/lib/modules/source
 tar xf vmhgfs.tar
 cd vmhgfs-only/
 sudo gedit inode.c
```

Go to line 888:

```
 result = compat_vmtruncate(inode, newSize);
```

And change it to:

```
 result = 0;
```

Then save the file and exit gedit.

```
 cd ..
 rm -rf vmhgfs.tar
 tar cf vmhgfs.tar vmhgfs-only/
 rm -rf vmhgfs-only/
```

Now restart the installing procedure. It worked for me in Xubuntu 13.04.

Src:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2136277&page=4&p=12709627#post12709627