# ubuntu 12.04 in vmware can't detect the shared folders

Tags: mac, shared-folders, vmware-fusion

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 via VMWare on MacOs 10.7.4.
I assigned a shared folder and gave ubuntu the right to read/write it.But now I can't find this folder in ubuntu. I know in win7 I can find it on desktop. Can you guys tell me what to do? Also the vmware tools were installed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is another askubuntu.com article that helped me with this problem:
[How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu using VMware tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-win7-host-in-ubuntu-guest-using-vmwaretools-v).

The article is meant for win7 but the solution also worked for my mac.