# Each time I reboot Ubuntu 12.4 in my vmware on Mac OS the share folder are not mounted

Tags: virtualization

I installed the VMwareTools-8.8.4. The shared folder was working fine. Each time I reboot Ubuntu 12.4 in my vmware on Mac OS the share folder are not mounted? Any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

So, MAC is the host and Ubuntu is the client.

It's the default behaviour, the VMware shared folders are basically folder shared over the network and without modifying `fstab` they are being mounted only when you need them.

You can follow this steps [How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu using VMware tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-win7-host-in-ubuntu-guest-using-vmwaretools-v)