# unable to see shared folders in ubuntu(guest) installed in vmware

Tags: vmware

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 in Vmware workstation in my windows7 OS. I installed VMware tools in Ubuntu.

I have configured the shared folders in settings. Using the below command, I am able to get shared folders

```
/usr/bin/vmware-hgfsclient
```

But the shared folders are not present `/mnt/hgfs`

I tried to install Vmware tools multiple time but no luck.

Comment: This solution worked for me on a Windows 10 host and Ubuntu 18: https://superuser.com/questions/1714957/vmware-vm-does-not-see-a-shared-folder

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps. It worked for me for ubuntu 14.04 LTS running in vmware.

Make sure open-vm-tools is not installed.
sudo apt-get remove open-vm-tools

1. Make sure the updates are done:
   sudo apt-get update
2. Make sure git is installed
   sudo apt-get install git
3. Run the command to get the tools from repository.
   sudo git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git
4. cd to vmware-tools-folder
   cd vmware-tools-patches
5. Run the patch
   sudo ./download-tools.sh
6. Run the following patch
   sudo ./untar-and-patch.sh
7. Run the complie.sh file
   sudo ./compile.sh

Comment: It takes some time, but it works!

Comment: I recently found shorter and simple solution. See below.

Comment: I did all those steps and it didn't help. I have ubuntu 18.04 on both host and guest

Comment: this doesn’t work anymore

Answer (score 1):

A good and short solution for me was:

```
sudo vmware-config-tools.pl
```

You may be needed to logout&login afterwords.

Comment: running it: `sudo ./vmware-tools-distrib/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl`, I get
`Unable to find the database file (/etc/vmware-tools/locations)`

Answer (score 0):

What problems did you have installing VMWare tools? I had a similar problem. After installing VMWare tools, I followed these instructions: [How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu using VMware tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-win7-host-in-ubuntu-guest-using-vmwaretools-v)

Running the vmware-config-tools.pl (  sudo vmware-config-tools.pl ) again, then rebooting solved the problem. The files are in /mnt/hgfs/[shared folder name]