# Enabling shared folders with open-vm-tools

Tags: mount, virtualization, vmware

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 in VMware Player on Windows 7. I have installed open-vm-tools instead of VMware Tools because VMware's software was unable to compile the kernel module required for file sharing. I cannot get my shared folder to mount with `sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/$(vmware-hgfsclient) /mnt/hgfs` or `sudo vmware-hgfsmounter .host:/$(vmware-hgfsclient) /mnt/hgfs`. Both return `Error: cannot canonicalize mount point: No such file or directory`. I have no idea what this is referring to or how to fix it.

Comment: current (as of May 2016) `open-vm-tools` package is buggy; you'll need to compile it yourself from source: https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/62

Answer (score 65):

My way of solving this issue is to resort to vmhgfs-fuse installed with open-vm-tools.

Either mount locally using `vmhgfs-fuse .host:/$(vmware-hgfsclient) ~/some_mountpoint` or globally using `sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other`. To then make mounting globally persistent add the following line to your `/etc/fstab`:

`.host:/ /mnt/hgfs fuse.vmhgfs-fuse allow_other 0 0`

Comment: The only thing I would add to this solution is that you might consider other file system options, for example "allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,auto_unmount,defaults". I installed the guest OS by pointing VMware at the downloaded ISO image. I did not explicitly let VMware install tools for me, and initially updated the Ubuntu installation. At that point open-vm-tools was installed, I did not have to install the package manually, and vmware-config-tools.pl did not appear to be part of the installed package.

Comment: Confirmed this works for 16.04 as well.

Comment: Works on 17.04 too and definitely a better solution than hacking the open-vm-tools

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 installed open-vm-tools , but there is no `vmhgfs-fuse`.

Comment: With Kubuntu 16.04.3 I installed package `open-vm-tools-desktop`, created directory `/mnt/hgf`, rebooted system, added `.host:/ /mnt/hgfs fuse.vmhgfs-fuse allow_other 0 0` to `/etc/fstab` and then `mount -a`.

Comment: verified with Ubuntu 17.10 "artful"

Comment: Worked for me on Q4OS.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, I was able to do this solely by adding this line to `/etc/fstab`:
`.host:/ /mnt/hgfs fuse.vmhgfs-fuse auto,allow_other 0 0`

Comment: mounting locally your way is creating the directory in a weird way - I can list it as super user, but I cannot enter it (`sudo cd`)

Answer (score 7):

As the other answers didn't work for me, I finally got it working after long time of digging from this link : [Files missing in /mnt/hgfs on Ubuntu VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591664/files-missing-in-mnt-hgfs-on-ubuntu-vm) where PieCot gives the solution:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git
$ cd vmware-tools-patches
$ ./patched-open-vm-tools.sh
```

Comment: This answer works, although I'm not sure it's enabling shared with folders with open-vm-tools. It seems to be downloading tools directly from vmware and patching them.

Comment: This was the only way I got it working (tried to build `open-vm-tools` from source but without a luck on Debian Jessie).  One small notice make sure your user is in sudoers list otherwise you had to remove `sudo` call from scripts and run commands from `patched-open-vm-tools.sh` manually as I did

Comment: Working here for Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS.

Comment: It didn't work for me. :-(

Answer (score 1):

On the VM make sure:

That you have folder sharing enabled

That you have at least one folder shared between the host and guest

On the Ubuntu guest:

Check /mnt/hgfs to see if you can access the folder, if your unable to do so run this tools command:

```
sudo vmware-config-tools.pl
```

Update the fstab using:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

Use a text editor to enter the following at the end of the file:

```
.host:/{shared-folder} /{path-to-mount-on} vmhgfs defaults,ttl=5,uid=1000,gid=1000   0 0
```

The final step is to restart your vm ( you may need to restart it , or get an error saying unable to mount, just skip this and restart a few times)!

Thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: I refered to this while answering your problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools

Comment: I'm not using VMware Tools, so "vmware-config-tools.pl" does not exist on my installation. I'm not using it because it gave me trouble before.

Comment: For this I'm using open-vm-tools. I couldn't get the instructions to work with VMware's software. Do you have anything else?

Comment: This may not work in newer versions of Ubuntu (later versions of 16.04 onwards). See: https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/248

Comment: You need to replace vmhgfs with vmhgfs on recent versions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737254/vmhgfs-fuse-at-boot-with-vmware-windows-8-1-host-and-ubuntu-16-04-guest

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 17.10 requires installing the vmhgfs driver through the proprietary VMWare Tools tar-based installation. For details see http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/Ubuntu_17_10.html

Answer (score 0):

This worket for me in Debian, I thing that will be the same on Ubuntu.

Install open-vm-tools-dkms package.

```
apt-get install open-vm-tools-dkms
```

Create a mount point.

```
mkdir /mnt/hgfs
```

Mount all chares in the mount point. With permission to all users

```
/usr/bin/vmware-vmblock-fuse /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other
```

Answer (score -1):

It simply means that your mount point does not exist.

```
$ ll /mnt
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Feb 22 20:37 ./
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Feb 22 20:16 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan  3 04:56 cdrom/

$ sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/Share /mnt/hgfs/Share
Error: cannot canonicalize mount point: No such file or directory

$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/hgfs/Share

$ ll /mnt/hgfs
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 22 20:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 22 20:52 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 22 20:52 Share/

$ sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/Share /mnt/hgfs/Share
```