# How can I access the host OS when using Ubuntu 22.04 or 22.10 with VM Tools Installed?

Tags: vmware

When I install Ubuntu 22.04 or 22.10 on the Mac (using VM Fusion 13), it automatically installs open vm tools. That's fine, good there is no longer a separate Install VM Tools step.

However, no matter what I've tried, I cannot access the host OS (the Mac drive I use for sharing, for example, I set up in VM Fusion). VM Fusion's shared access says the shared folder won't be available until VM Tools is installed and running. Yet open vm tools are reported as installed and running. vm tools desktop is also installed and running, but no apparent way to access it, either.

Also, there is no option in VM Fusion to "install" VM Tools. Well, there is a "Re-install VM Tools", but it's grayed out.

There is nothing installed in Ubuntu's /mnt folder.

Looking in the Ubuntu File app's "Other Locations" only shows me the local Ubuntu disk and "Windows Network". Clicking on Windows Network gives me an error that there is nothing available there.

Since I have VM Fusion set up with Windows 10 with no issues accessing VM Fusion shared folders on the Host OS, I believe the Mac's (OS 13.2) permissions are not the issue.

But what is the issue? How do I get to the host OS folder I shared. VM Fusion says VM Tools are not running (well really that the VM Fusion shared folder won't be available until VM Tools are running).

No matter what I've tried, I simply cannot see the host's shared folder with Ubuntu. Although vm tools is installed and "running", it doesn't seem to be giving me any access.

This is now a five-day problem. I just need to get a large file from the host OS onto Ubuntu for testing.

Comment: Couldn't you use an application like WinSCP (but for MacOS) to transfer files to the Ubuntu OS via SSH/SCP?

Comment: Thank you for that idea, but my goal is to be able to share files between host and VM like I was able to do with Ubuntu in the past.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! "Since I have VM Fusion set up with Windows 10 with no issues accessing VM Fusion shared folders on the Host OS, I believe the Mac's (OS 13.2) permissions are not the issue." This assumes facts not in evidence. How is access handled when sharing the resource with the windows system? are the user credentials identical on the Ubuntu system? My best advice currently is for you to re-examine your assumptions and verify each and every one of them is correct and verifiable.

Comment: I've spent days examining everything possible. I was only mentioning Windows as a separate example. if you have any helpful suggestions or you can explain how I can see my shared host drive set up in VM Fusion, please post those...

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I finally found that worked: https://gist.github.com/darrenpmeyer/b69242a45197901f17bfe06e78f4dee3

> (**NB:** adapted from [this Ask Ubuntu
> thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580319/enabling-shared-folders-with-open-vm-tools)
> -- tested to work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS through Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy).
>
> Unlike using VMWare Tools to enable Linux guest capabilities, the
> `open-vm-tools` package doesn't auto-mount shared VMWare folders. This
> can be frustrating in various ways, but there's an easy fix.
>
> ## TL;DR
>
> Install `open-vm-tools` and run:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other
> ```
>
> (Make sure /mnt/hgfs exists and is empty)
>
> You can put configuration stanzas in `/etc/fstab` to facilitate this,
> and then `mount /mnt/hgfs` will work.
>
> See the **Setting up auto-mounting** section for setting up
> auto-mounting instead.
>
> ## Pre-work
>
> Make sure `open-vm-tools` (and `open-vm-tools-desktop` if you're using
> a desktop environment) are installed, and that you've rebooted after
> their installation.
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
> ```
>
> Make sure you have a `/mnt/hgfs` directory made and empty. If not:
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir -p /mnt/hgfs
> ```
>
> ## Mounting
>
> To mount the filesystem, run:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other
> ```
>
> The shared folders will now be in subdirectories of `/mnt/hgfs`
>
> ## Setting up auto-mounting
>
> Add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:
>
> ```
> .host:/   /mnt/hgfs   fuse.vmhgfs-fuse    auto,allow_other    0   0
> ```
>
> **Update:** based on extensive testing, the `auto` keyword seems to work fine. Prior versions suggested `noauto`. If you have trouble with
> `auto`, change to `noauto` and see below
>
> ### If using the `noauto` keyword, but you want automount
>
> 1. Create or edit the script `/etc/rc.local` (as root), and add the line:
>
>    ```
>    mount /mnt/hgfs
>    ```
> 2. make sure `rc.local` is executable and owned by root:
>
>    ```
>    sudo chown root:root /etc/rc.local
>    sudo chmod 0755 /etc/rc.local
>    ```
> 3. enable the `rc.local` service in systemd:
>
>    ```
>    sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
>    ```
> 4. reboot
>
> The `rc.local` script runs as the last step of startup, allowing the
> HGFS filesystem to mount after `open-vm-tools` services are running,
> which is required for successful operation.
>
> Browse `/mnt/hgfs` at will.