# How do I mount a Shared Folder from a Vmware Workstation Host (Windows 7) inside Ubuntu

Tags: directory, virtualization

I have been trying to do this for days now and I am getting no where. I have downloaded the latest Vmware Tools. What steps/commands do I use? Please help

Gary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu using VMware tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools)