# Unable to mount windows share under vmplayer 12

Tags: 14.04, vmware, vmware-player, vmware-tools

So this feels like one of those common problems where the suggested solutions just fail to apply to my situation.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 installation running on wmplayer 12 under windows 7. I have the shared folder option set to 'always enabled' but I cannot access the shared folder on the host.

When I try to mount folder I get the following error:

```
# mount vmware-hgfsmounter .host:/svn /mnt/hgfs
ERROR: cannot mount filesystem: No such device
```

- The mount point /mnt/hgfs exists.
- I have successfully cun vmware-config-tools.pl and build the hgfs module without error.
- I have installed open-vm-tools and it can be restarted without error.
- vmware-hgfsclient lists the svn folder.

I have previously had luck using the suggestions from the third answer in this thread (but without any luck this time): [How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu using VMware tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a known bug in the VMware Tools where it doesn't work with certain kernels; this is a known issue that has no resolution at this time.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, except I am using Windows 10 host.

Comment: @ThomasW. Which kernels? I am happy to run a different kernel if it resolves the issue.

Comment: @NicuStiurca last I got it working was 12.04, between 12.04 and 14.04 it stopped working, never could figure out the solution.  It's an issue with the VMware Tools themselves, not the host.  Not that hard though to use Windows 10 sharing to run a fileshare and have Ubuntu hook into them to share data across

Answer (score 0):

Using that source:
https://communities.vmware.com/message/2510025#2510025

I composed joined command:

```bash
sudo apt-get remove open-vm-tools; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install git; sudo git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git; cd vmware-tools-patches; sudo ./download-tools.sh; sudo ./untar-and-patch.sh; sudo ./compile.sh
```

After that you will see shared folder.
Keep in mind, at the time of command executing, dozen of vmware tools different versions are download and installed and it takes around 1 hour.