# vmware tools and gcc installed, but gcc path "invalid." (Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: vmware, gcc, vmware-workstation

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 in a VM using vmware workstation, and trying to get the guest OS to see the shared directory. I have installed vmware tools using the VM menu.

Afterwards, `vmware-hgfsclient` returns the name of the shared directory from Windows, but it is not mounted in /mnt/hgfs (although that directory does exist.

I followed the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools) and ran `vmware-config-tools.pl`

It goes smoothly until it wants to configure hgfs, and asks for the path to the gcc binary. According to `which gcc` it's installed in /usr/bin/gcc. However, when I specify that path I get an error saying that the path is invalid, and I am unable to get any further.

I've done a lot of searching on this error and have tried a bunch of different things (at this point I've lost track of everything I've tried), and so am hoping somebody can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Error message:

```
Searching for GCC...
The path "" is not valid path to the gcc binary.
Would you like to change it? [yes] 

What is the location of the gcc program on your machine? /usr/bin/gcc

The path "/usr/bin/gcc" is not valid path to the gcc binary.
Would you like to change it? [yes]
```

Comment: I've upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 and am having the same problem.

Comment: Can you please include the exact error message?

Comment: updated original post