# Auto mount a shared folder using autofs service with VmwarePlayer

Tags: virtualization, vmware, shared-folders, vmware-player

I'm running Ubuntu Budgie in a virtual machine using VMware Player.

To mount the shared folder I use:

```
sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other
```

but I need to run the command every time when I use the VM.

So, in `auto.master` I added

```
/mnt /etc/auto.shared
```

and in `auto.shared`

```
shared -fstype=fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/shared
```

also tried

```
shared -fstype=auto .host:/shared
shared -fstype=auto .host:/
shared -fstype=fuse.vmhgfs-fuse host:/
```

Nothing works, doesn't create/load the 'shared' folder from host

Comment: Answered at https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools