# How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu (version >= 18.04) using VMware tools?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, 19.04, vmware, vmware-tools

*(migrating this ticket to have correct answer for recent Ubuntu-s. Originally asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools), but most answers are obsolete.)*

I've successfully installed VMware tools for Ubuntu. Everything seems to work fine, but shared folders were not mounted automatically. How do I get them to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu using VMware tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools)

Comment: No. That is why I created this Q&A. (Read with understanding. I referenced the very same ticket, that you put in your comment, both in the question and in the answer.) 1. That Q&A is 10 years old. 2. Full of obsolete stuff. 3. The accepted answer does not work. I flagged that Q&A for moderator intervention. This Q&A answers the question for modern Ubuntu-s. Cheers.

Comment: @24601 Thank you for your input, but this is not constructive. 1. The old Q&A should be deleted based on the moderation rules (the old one is not relevant to mainstream Ubuntu. 2. If, as an user, I open that series of Answers (did that), it is super confusing why I have to dig through changes that are completely irrelevant to the question or recent Ubuntu's. 3. If you check my profile, you will see that I am not new to StackExchange, and I am actually trying to clean up the mess, and instead of you helping, you create an issue here. Cheers.

Comment: @TFuto The answer you copied has _currently_ the most upvotes. So everything is working fine, no need to copy it somewhere else. Read [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/828/1060743) for good/best practices to solve your problem. Or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302/11942268) for possible features of the future.

Comment: @stackprotector: To be honest, I dug quite long to find this answer, and I made changes based on (incorrect) answers that 1. did not work and 2. I had to undo. Now, those answers might work for older Ubuntu (there is historical value - sometimes I have to boot very old Ubuntus as well), but the default, accepted answer should "just work". I got your recommendations. I flagged old entries. There was no response or cleanup activity. There should be a feature to 1. tag answers with correct versions and 2. auto-hide answers not related to current Ubu versions. I will review the meta talk. Thanks.

Comment: @stackprotector (Also, I don't have enough point here yet to make large scale cleanup of entries.)

Answer (score 0):

*(I am copying the answer of @con-f-use here from [How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu using VMware tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools) for good housekeeping. If he re-creates his answer here, please upvote that, and I will accept that.)*

For Ubuntu 18.04 (or recent Debian distros), try:

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs/ -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```

If the `hgfs` directory doesn't exist, try:

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/ -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```

You may have use a specific folder instead of `.host:/`. In that case you can find out the share's name with `vmware-hgfsclient`. For example:

```
$ vmware-hgfsclient
my-shared-folder
$ sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/my-shared-folder /mnt/hgfs/ -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```

If you want them mounted on startup, update `/etc/fstab` with the following:

```
# Use shared folders between VMWare guest and host
.host:/    /mnt/hgfs/    fuse.vmhgfs-fuse    defaults,allow_other,uid=1000     0    0
```

I choose to mount them on demand and have them ignored by `sudo mount -a` and the such with the `noauto` option, because I noticed the shares have an impact on VM performance.

### Requirements

Software requirements may require installing the following tools beforehand:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Others have claimed the following are required:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant \
  linux-headers-virtual linux-image-virtual && dpkg-reconfigure open-vm-tools
```