# The shared folders not shown in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: vmware, shared-folders, sharing

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and successfully shared folders in VMware. However, I find my `mnt` folder is empty. So, I use `sudo mkdir /mnt/hgfs` codes to make `mnt` have a folder named `hgfs`. However, the `ghfs` folded is still empty. What should I do to see the shared folders in Ubuntu?

Comment: Why should it be not empty?  Why are you thinking that shared folders should appear in `/mnt`?

Comment: @Pilot6 I see other's answers that the shared folder will be in `/mnt`

Comment: Can you give a link to these "other's answers"?

Comment: @Pilot6 `https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-access-a-vmware-shared-folder-on-ubuntu/#:~:text=Inside%20the%20root%20folder%2C%20locate,it%20to%20access%20your%20files.`

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem so I run this command:

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs/ -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```

as explained in this link:
[How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu using VMware tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools)

After that i browsed the path /mnt/hgfs and I was able to access to my shared folder.