# Accessing shared folder in ubuntu from VMWare workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

How do I mount shared folder in Ubuntu from VMware Workstation?

Comment: Usually you could create a shared folder between your vm and ubuntu. But not "the"folder" that resides in your VM. The basic idea: You have a folder on your "host" system that can be shared with your "guest" system. Read the manual.(Vbox provides this feature)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mount shared folders in Ubuntu using VMware tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools)